# Connect button greyed out for Wireless Network Authentication Required menu

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, connection

I am trying to connect to a network using the options:

Wireless security: WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
Authentication: TLS

I have entered values for my identity, user certificate, ca certificate, private key and private key password.  However the "connect" button is greyed out.  Is this dialogue performing some kind of check that is failing, or is this just a bug?

Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure it out? Take a look at this. Connecting with nmcli from the terminal should at the least give you an error message so you may get a clue as to what the problem is.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-tiphow-to-connectdisconnect-vpn-from-the-command-line.html

If you run `nmcli con list` does the VPN you named show up in the list?

Comment: Hey, my VPN shows up on the list, but connecting via my user or via sudo gives me the same error: `Error: Connection activation failed: the VPN service failed to start.`

Comment: Do you know which protocol your VPN host is using? Ask your VPN host or check their online documentation if available. You may need to install a different VPN package. The packages available for each protocol, according to [VPNClient](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient), are pptp-linux, vpnc an openvpn.

Comment: THanks! but no, as its an office network, I am blind on their config. I have a windows PC connected to the network and if there is anything I can check on it to get the info (without installing anything) then I can get it. AS far as protocols go, PAP, CHAP, EAP are disabled for me. Can you help me which packages i need to install for them to be enabled?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what else to suggest. If you run `which openvpn` and see that it is installed, you could try to re-install that package and see if it doesn't configure itself.

Comment: that command gave no output or errors,

Comment: Then you probably don't have openvpn installed. If you take a look at `ls -a /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` what does it show?

Comment: If you're using vpnc, I keep reading that the conf file needs to have root permissions. The probem is that I can't know whether your office is using Cisco VPN(vpnc), openvpn or something else. This is the clearest document on [Installing vpnc](http://www.id.uzh.ch/neu/notebook/vpn/install_7.html) that I've seen, including the part about setting root permissions on the conf file. Otherwise, it could be as simple as installing openvpn.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. I will try your suggestions and get back to you. For now, all I can tell you is that we use Juniper Network Connect to connect to the VPN when connecting from other places. Wonder if that can help decide if the office folks use openvpn or cisco or something else?

Comment: Here is the output of     `ls -a /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`       `VPN connection 1  VPN connection 1~  Wired connection 1  ZTE`